# Is there any way to access an outer scope's variable once the present scope has defined one of the same name?

Tags: javascript

It would seem not:

```
function o(){
  var v = 1;
  function i(){
    var v = 2;
    // any way at all, now, to access the 1 value?
  }
}
```

But is there?

Comment: If the "outer scope" you're referring to is global variables, then the browser exposes them as `window.varname`, which means that the answer is "yes, they are accessible". I know that doesn't answer the question with regard to other layers of scope, but for globals you do have an option.

Answer (score 4):

No, within `i` the `v` symbol completely shadows the `v` in `o`, and there's no other way to get at it. With that code, there's no way for `i` to get at `o`'s `v`.

Of course, if you used different names for the variables, that problem goes away. :-)

---

If instead of `o` you had code at *global* scope, you could access `v` as a property of the global object, because when you declare a variable globally, it becomes a property of the global object. For instance, this would work in loose mode:

```
var v = 1;
function i() {
    var v = 2;
    console.log("v == " + v);
    console.log("this.v == " + this.v);
}
i(); // Calling it like this makes `this` within the call the global object
```

Which would show

```
v == 2;
this.v == 1
```

That wouldn't work in strict mode, though, because `this` would be `undefined` within `i`.

On browsers, the global object has a property, `window`, it uses to refer to itself, so you wouldn't have to rely on `this` as with the above:

```
// Browsers only
var v = 1;
function i() {
    var v = 2;
    console.log("v == " + v);
    console.log("window.v == " + window.v);
}
i();
```

That works in either strict or loose mode, but only in browsers.

But global scope is a special case. For the code you quoted, no, there's no way to get there.